# My root doesn't seem to be updating after delete

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Okay so for my project, I am making a dictionary using AVL tree. I have successfully enabled my insert and balance functions. But when I use my delete function, it doesn't do anything. I am new so I may be ignoring some basic mistake or blunder. Please help

I've tried different methods, but it just doesn't seem to update. I am using C++ classes for the first time I didn't had this problem in java.

```
struct pBook
{
  string key;
  string email;
  string phNum;
  string phType;
  int height;
  pBook *left;
  pBook *right;
};
class Phonebook
{
private:
  pBook *root;
public:
  pBook* deleteC(pBook *node, std::string key)
  {
    if (node == NULL)
    {
      return node;
    }
    else if (!compare(key, node->key))
    {
      node->left = deleteC(node->left, key);
    }
    else if (compare(key, node->key))
    {
      node->right = deleteC(node->right, key);
    }
    else
    {
      if (node == NULL)
      {
        cout << "Error\n";
      }
      else if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)
      {
        delete node;
      }
      else if (node->left == NULL)
      {
        pBook *temp = node->right;
        free(temp);
        return node;
      }
      else if (node->right == NULL)
      {
        pBook *temp = node->left;
        free(temp);
        return node;
      }
      else
      {
        pBook *temp = minValueNode(node->right);
        node->key = temp->key;
        node->right = deleteC(root->right, temp->key);
      }
      return node;
    }
    return node;
  }
  pBook * minValueNode(pBook *node)
  {
    pBook *current = node;
    while (current && current->left != NULL)
      current = current->left;
    return current;
  }
  void callDelete(pBook *node,std::string key)
  {
    deleteC(root, key);
    root = node;
  }
};
```

There is no difference in result before deleting and after deleting.

Comment: Mixing `free()` and `delete` is certainly not a good idea. Also note that neither method automatically sets the deleted pointer to `NULL`, but yoiur code seems to rely on such behavior.

Comment: question: ```compare``` is a public member function - is it possible to use it like this ```compare(key, node->key)```?

Comment: well I first tried delete, then free both didn't work. Can you give me the right method for it? I am so confused

Comment: @Croppi I made it to compare both strings lexicographically and it works fine. I did insertion and balancing using this method too and it worked fine

Comment: Solved the issue was in implementation of compare(); Thanks